# Space between LinearLayout children in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, layout, horizontalscrollview

I'm having trouble separating children in a LinearLayout which is a child of a HorizontalScrollView. I have tried with numerous approaches on the LinearLayout element (padding_right, layout_margin, divider) but none of them working. Picture below illustrate what I would like to achieve(The top is the expected result whereas bottom 1 is the rendered result of my layout)

[image: Top is Expected Result, Bottom is Current Facing Problem]

Here's the 2 layouts which I'm using:

layout/activity_main.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@id/horizontal_scroll_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/id"
            layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/id"
            layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/id"
            layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/id"
            layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/id"
            layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/id"
            layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

layout/gallery_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/galleryItemLayout"
    android:layout_width="139.0dip"
    android:layout_height="130.0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/gallery_item_selector"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/galleryItemView"
        android:layout_width="139.0dip"
        android:layout_height="78.0dip"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:padding="0.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/articleTitleId"
        android:layout_width="139.0dip"
        android:layout_height="50.0dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/galleryItemView"
        android:background="#ff0a0a0a"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="2.0dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="13.0sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the rendered result of some attempts:

**Using layout_marginLeft:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
```

[image]

**Using paddingLeft:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/content_scroll"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="20dp" >
```

[image]

Comment: set custom layout margin.

Comment: @SurenderKumar i did. but the result apply on the parent. I will post some screenshot here for my attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try applying margin to the include layout

```
  <include 
android:id="@+id/id"
 layout="@layout/gallery_item_layout"
    android:layout_margin="2dp" />
```

Comment: this works but the result comes out as a "pink region" when I turned on the "Show Layout Boundary" option. The layout in bbc apps doesn't have this and appears as a clear/empty region. any idea?

Comment: can you share me the screenshot of it, it helps me understand properly

Comment: it's similar to the second last screenshot above except the pink region is between the boxes.

Comment: try removing marginleft from it or try applying transparent color background

Comment: maybe I should rephrase my question. Your solution works. just that it seems like the bbc app is not using layoutmargin to space out the elements. any alternative that you could think of? Because using margin it will show as pink region under "Show Layout Boundary" in "Developer Options"

Answer (score 2):

You should add your margins to your `gallery_item_layout.xml`

So in your `gallery_item_layout.xml` insert margins for your root RelativeLayout

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

Alternatively you can add margins to every include element in your `activity_main.xml` but if you take this approach you have to specify the `layout_width` and `layout_height` parameters for each include element as well. Otherwise margins will be ignored.

Comment: this works but the result comes out as a "pink region" when I turned on the "Show Layout Boundary" option. The layout in bbc apps doesn't have this and appears as a clear/empty region. any idea?

Comment: I don't have any idea how they do it in bbc app. Seems they have somehow did it using padding instead of margins. But I don't have any clue about it. Will let you if I found any thing. But as long as the final outcome is fine with you, I think its not really a matter how you implement it

Answer (score 0):

In your layout/gallery_item_layout.xml

Width of `galleryItemLayout` should be atleast 2dp more than that of `galleryItemView` and `articleTitleId` if you are giving padding of 2dp

Comment: and how this solve the interspacing problem in main_activity?